# How do I set an environment variable dynamically when using poetry shell?

Tags: python, virtualenv, gnupg, python-poetry, tty

When I activate a virtual environment via `poetry shell`, GPG signing gets messed up because `$GPG_TTY` is set for the parent shell. So every time I use `poetry shell` I have to do `GPG_TTY=$(tty)`. Is there a way to do this automatically? Ideally I would set this up once globally rather than for every poetry project.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Poetry does include a plugin system from version 1.2 onwards, and [`.env` support](https://pypi.org/project/poetry-dotenv-plugin/) - if that works for your use case - has been one of the first plugins being written. You can activate it with

```bash
poetry self add poetry-dotenv-plugin
```

---

If plugins are not for you, this pattern works with most shells and will work globally for your user:

**~/.bashrc**

```
alias poetry="GPG_TTY=$(tty) poetry"
```

Comment: Thanks for the info about the plugin system. The problem here is that I can't set the environmental value until the poetry shell has been created, so this approach won't work. `tty` outside the poetry shell gives the wrong value. I'm basically asking if there's a way to hook into the `shell` command to run some script every time the shell is created.

Comment: I see. well, in that case any approach trying to solve this on the bash-level is bound to fail, since exports and the like always happen before the sub-shell is entered. I imagine it should be possible to solve this with plugins, though.

Answer (score 6):

The answer for Arne is correct, however you should use `poetry self add poetry-dotenv-plugin` with more recent versions of poetry.