# Why can't Poetry load my environment variables?

Tags: python-venv, python-poetry

I'm trying to get Poetry to load env vars from a file when the .venv is activated. I can't use the plugin to load a .env because I'm not allowed to use Poetry 1.2.

I've got my env vars in a file called `creds.sh`.
I've edited both my `.venv\Scripts\activate` and `.venv\Scripts\activate.bat` to source from that file:

```
set -a
. creds.sh
set +a
```

and,

```
for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%G in (%~dp0..\..\creds.sh) do set %%G=%%H
```

respectively.

When I open up a new bash, and `\activate`, it works. I can `env | grep <my var>` and find my vars.
When I open up a new cmd, and `\activate.bat`, it works. I can again `env | grep <my var>` and find my vars.

When I `poetry shell` or `poetry run my-script`, it can't find my vars! What the heck is going on.
One thought is somehow poetry's opening up some other kind of shell, so I've tried to look for the `$SHELL` var inside my `.venv` but it doesn't seem to exist.

Any ideas? How else might I inject env vars into the Poetry env when the env is activated?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [How do I set an environment variable dynamically when using poetry shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67107007/how-do-i-set-an-environment-variable-dynamically-when-using-poetry-shell):

- You need poetry v 1.2 or above
- run `poetry plugin add poetry-dotenv-plugin`

Comment: I'm working on an airgapped machine with no access to v1.2 or plugins. Seems like there's no other way to do this. Oh well!

Comment: you can use same-shell-line variables!
`VARIABLE=value poetry <other-args>`