# Pass Arguments to pyproject.toml and conf.py files from Docker Compose File

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, configuration, python-poetry

I have a project with a `pyproject.toml` file containing metadata such as `name, version, description`, and `authors`. Additionally, I have a `conf.py` file that includes `project`, `author`, and `version` information. I want to pass these values as arguments to my Docker Compose file to automate the setup process. How can I achieve this?

I would like to dynamically set the values of the following fields in my Docker Compose file using the metadata from `pyproject.toml` and `conf.py`:

- Project name
- Project version
- Project description
- Authors

Tree Structure:

```
project/
├── docker-compose.yml
├── pyproject.toml
└── docs/
    └── conf.py
```

Contents of `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  myapp:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - PROJECT_NAME=${PROJECT_NAME}
        - PROJECT_VERSION=${PROJECT_VERSION}
        - PROJECT_DESCRIPTION=${PROJECT_DESCRIPTION}
        - AUTHORS=${AUTHORS}
```

Contents of `pyproject.toml`:

```
[project]
name = "My Project"
version = "1.0.0"
description = "A sample project"
authors = ["John Doe", "Jane Smith"]
```

Contents of `docs/conf.py`:

```
project = 'My Project'
author = 'John Doe, Jane Smith'
version = '1.0.0'
```

Is there a way to extract these values from the respective files and pass them as arguments to the Docker Compose file during the setup process? Any guidance or examples on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Should these files be checked into source control?  If your repository says it's `My Project` version 1.0, why would the Docker image change it to `A Different Project` version 2.6?

Comment: I already use source control for the project, the `version` is a part of the `Sphinx` and `Poetry` . Leaving the version field empty or unspecified in the `pyproject.toml` file can cause issues when managing dependencies and when publishing your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue you have- is that you're trying to build the Python package using `docker-compose`. A better way is to use only `docker build` to create it, but if it's a part of CI, better to do one step before modifying these.

1. If you want to stick your own way, you can try using `dotenv` plugin: [How do I set an environment variable dynamically when using poetry shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67107007/how-do-i-set-an-environment-variable-dynamically-when-using-poetry-shell)
2. Better way, before you start `docker build`, use [toml cli](https://pypi.org/project/toml-cli/) to set the changes you want. For example change the version by:

```
toml set --toml-path pyproject.toml tool.poetry.version 0.2.0
```

Comment: thank you the `toml cli` seems like a reasonable solution. Could you expand on what you mean by `CI`? How about the Sphinx `conf.py` file do you have a way possibly for me to use Dockerfile to set that?

Comment: CI stands for "continuous integration". During GitLab CI we use `toml set` to modify the version, author, and more. About Sphinx - not sure what is the best practice here, but found some resources support `Sphinx.toml` to modify it.